# gulp & webpack: ERROR in Entry module not found

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp

I use `webpack` for working with JavaScript (ES6 modules bundling, converting to ES5, etc.) and `gulp` - for other tasks (`jade`, `sass`, etc.). I want to keep the `webpack` configuration in `webpack.config.js`, but to execute `webpack` by `gulp` task.

---

### Project structure

**development**

**es6** - source JS

main.js

**js** - output JS for development

index.js

**production**

webpack.config.js

gulpfile.js

---

### gulpfile.js

```
var  gulp = require('gulp'), 
        //...
     gulpwebpack = require('gulp-webpack')
        
        
gulp.task('gulpwebpack', function(){ 
   
    return gulp.src('development/03_es6/main.js')
        .pipe(gulpwebpack(require('./webpack.config.js')))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('development/js/'));
  
});

// ...

gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync', 'jade', 'sass'], function() {
    // ...
    gulp.watch('development/03_es6/*.js', ['test']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

---

### webpack.config.js

```
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

module.exports = {
    
    context: __dirname + '/development',
    
    entry: './03_es6/main.js',
    
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/development/js/',
        filename: 'index.js'
    },
        
    module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.jsx?$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: ['babel-loader']
                }
            ]
        }
    
    //watch: NODE_ENV === 'development'
};
```

---

### Problem

If just to execute `webpack` from the console (it means to execute the `webpack` independently from `gulp`), everything will be correct. However, if to execute `gulp gulpwebpack`, the error message will appear:

```
 ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./development/03_es6/main.js in C:\...\projectFrolder/development
```

I understand that the origin of error is here:

```
// ...

context: __dirname + '/development',

entry: './03_es6/main.js',

output: {

// ...
```

However `development/03_es6/main.js` and `./development/03_es6/main.js` will not work too. Gulp can not read `webpack.config.js` correctly, isn't it?

Comment: `path.resolve(__dirname, '/development')`

Comment: Thank you for the comment answer. Please tell me where I need to add this row. In `webpack2` config, resolving defining in `resolve: { ... } `, but it looks like that I need to add `path.resolve(__dirname, '/development')` somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you should switch to

```js
'use strict';

const gulp = require('gulp'),
      named = require('vinyl-named'),
      webpack = require('webpack-stream');

gulp.task('webpack', function () {
  gulp.src('development/03_es6/main.js')
      .pipe(named())
      .pipe(webpack(require('./webpack.config.js')))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'))
});
```

Remove entry from webpack.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {

context: __dirname + '/development',

output: {
    path: __dirname + '/development/js/',
    filename: 'index.js'
},

module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your settings are works! Would you please to explain about `vynil-named` role in this settings?